# MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage fails on Samsung tablets

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

My code crashes **only** on Samsung Galaxy tablets (e.g. SM-P601, Android 4.4.2).

The code that crashes is this line:

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), null, "ShareImage", null);
```

Another code that fails is just in OnClick method:

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(128, 128, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), bm, "ShareImage", null);
Log.d("tag", path);
```

The exception is:

> 08-07 12:20:41.703  14625-14849/com.mypackage.testapp.testing
>   E/MediaStore﹕ Failed to insert image
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
>               at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
>               at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:611)
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:925)
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:672)
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:648)
>               at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:937)

- My context object in this case is application context passed to this
  method.
- I have added all the permissions to read and write external storage
- Again it happens only on specific samsung tablets
- The issue is not with bitmap, it doesn't work event if I create an empty bitmap.
- The following code is executed on button click
- Application does not crash, only exception appears in logs.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059580/mediastore-images-media-insertimage-is-returning-null-when-trying-to-save-the-im) Doesn't help me.

UPD.

After a few seconds this exception appears:

> 08-07 12:56:13.038    1841-1852/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception
>   to parcel
>       java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
>               at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
>               at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:341)
>               at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
>               at com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider.GallerySearchDatabase.setTableForTag(GallerySearchDatabase.java:137)
>               at com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider.GallerySearchDatabase.getImages(GallerySearchDatabase.java:559)
>               at com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider.GallerySearchProvider.getFindoSuggest(GallerySearchProvider.java:107)
>               at com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider.GallerySearchProvider.getFindoTagSuggest(GallerySearchProvider.java:111)
>               at com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider.GallerySearchProvider.query(GallerySearchProvider.java:81)
>               at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:857)
>               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
>               at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void fixMediaDir() {
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (sdcard == null) { return; }
    File dcim = new File(sdcard, "DCIM");
    if (dcim == null) { return; }
    File camera = new File(dcim, "Camera");
    if (camera.exists()) { return; }
    camera.mkdir();
}
```