# MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage - java.io.FileNotFoundException - Android

Tags: android, image, uri, mediastore

> Note: similar question is asked over below SO links, but none of the
>   proposed solution worked for me, hence starting this thread.

1. [MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage is returning null when trying
   to save the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059580/mediastore-images-media-insertimage-is-returning-null-when-trying-to-save-the-im)
2. [Why Images.Media.insertImage return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230942/why-images-media-insertimage-return-null)

**Problem statement:**
I am downloading the image from a url and then trying to share the same. To achieve this I need the Uri, which I am obtaining by saving the image in MediaStore.Images.Media.

**Code:**

A. Obtained downloaded image from an AsyncTask class

```
public void processDownloadedImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Image could not be downloaded and shared!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            downloadedImage = bitmap;
            checkPermissionShowShareSheet();
        }
    }
```

B. Checking permission for Marshmallow and higher

```
public void checkPermissionShowShareSheet() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},2909);
            }
            else {


            updateImageUri(downloadedImage);
            showShareSheet(downloadedImageUri);
        }
    }
    else {
        updateImageUri(downloadedImage);
        showShareSheet(downloadedImageUri);
    }
}
```

C. Obtaining image Uri

```
private void updateImageUri(Bitmap inImage){
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        fixMediaDir();
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), inImage, "SomeImage", null);
        storePathInSharedPreferences(path);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        downloadedImageUri = uri;
    }

    void fixMediaDir() {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sdcard != null) {
            File mediaDir = new File(sdcard, "DCIM/Camera");
            if (!mediaDir.exists()) {
                mediaDir.mkdirs();
            }
        }
    }
```

D. Manifest file uses permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Problem:** value returned from below line is null

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), inImage, "SomeImage", null);
```

Any ideas?

**Here is portion of Stackbacktrace:**

```
Failed to insert image java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory       
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:620)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:939)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:686)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:662)
at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:934)
at myorg.myapp.ImageDescription.updateImageUri(ImageDescription.java:165)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_external_storage" />
```

To

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: did but same result :( .. path is still null

Comment: I have updated my post with a portion of stack backtrace, please have a look