# Android get file path of image with in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have an app and I need to take photos and then upload it to firebase. I basically need Uri path of the photo taken.

I read [Get file path of image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432592/get-file-path-of-image-on-android), but I have a problem with NullPointerException.

Main difference between my problem and the problem above is that I'm doing it in a Fragment.

Here is my code:

```
mTakePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

I get NullPointerException in line with Uri imgUri.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            mImgView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            Uri imgUri = getImageUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), photo);
            mManager.setPhotoUri(imgUri);
        }
}
```

And here is the method I use to get Uri.

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

The exact error message is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:1, request=22222, result=-1,
>   data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity
>   {.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString

I would appreciate any help.

The entire error log:

> 09-14 12:06:18.448 16497-16497/com.example.radzik.recipes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.radzik.recipes, PID: 16497
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:1, request=22222, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.radzik.recipes/com.example.radzik.recipes.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
>                                                                                   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java:475)
>                                                                                   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java)
>                                                                                   at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:437)
>                                                                                   at com.example.radzik.recipes.fragment.ChoosePhotoFragment.getImageUri(ChoosePhotoFragment.java:144)
>                                                                                   at com.example.radzik.recipes.fragment.ChoosePhotoFragment.onActivityResult(ChoosePhotoFragment.java:135)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6452)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Can you post the entire error log that also contains the stack frame?

Comment: I've updated my question with full error

Comment: It looks like the `insertImage` call is returning `null` and hence the `path` is `null`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059580/mediastore-images-media-insertimage-is-returning-null-when-trying-to-save-the-im

Comment: I'll check it out. Great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `getActivity()` becasue you are getting the intent of the current activity you were on which will fail.
So if you move your code to the `OnActivityResult` this will make it work.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //first call super
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //rest of your code
}
```

Don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and/or without depends on your app

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: Made a mistake in question, it's inside onActivityResult. Thanks for pointing that out!